# Loading local html file in Android browser through intents

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, android-intent

I need to parse a local HTML file in the google chrome browser. I have read that a way of doing this, is to copy the HTML file into the SD card and load it. What I want to do is, open the HTML file in the chrome browser from the MyProject/assets folder.

I am currently loading the html through a url. Loading the html locally would make the page load faster. This is what I am doing right now.

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
    startActivity(i);
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.setData(Uri.parse("MyProject/assets/htmlfile.html"));
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the `setComponent()` call. Treat your users with respect, and allow them to use whatever browser they wish. Besides, Chrome is only on a small percentage of Android devices, meaning that your app will crash on most devices.

Second, get rid of the `addCategory()` call, and replace your `Intent` action with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

All of that should be done regardless of where you are getting your Web content from, as your current approach is incorrect and unreliable.

With respect to assets, other apps cannot directly read your assets via a `Uri`. You can create a `ContentProvider` that serves your assets, but Chrome does not support the `content://` `Uri` scheme. In fact, Chrome only supports `http://` and `https://` `Uri` values for loading arbitrary URLs -- it does not even seem to support `file://` very well.

If you want to view an asset, display it in a `WebView` widget. There, you can use a `file:///android_asset/` URL to reference one of your own app's assets.

Comment: The reason it has to load on chrome is because of the WebRTC functionality provided by chrome. I tried the WebView widget but I guess the android browser does not support the functionalities I need the browser to perform. Hence the setComponent() call. Is there any way around this.

Comment: @earb: "The reason it has to load on chrome is because of the WebRTC functionality provided by chrome" -- that does not address whether the user wants Chrome or whether the user has Chrome. After all, Mozilla Firefox and Opera Mobile also support WebRTC, at least according to Wikipedia. "Is there any way around this" -- load your content from the Web. Or, use the WebRTC native API from C/C++ code (see http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started).